# Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder' but tfv1 is imported

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to run following code:

```
input_img = Input((height, width, 1), name='img')
model = get_unet(input_img, n_filters=16, dropout=0.05, batchnorm=True)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

But I'm getting "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'".
Everywhere it is recommended to use

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

But I still keep getting such error.

Comment: Are you using Anaconda distribution

Comment: Yes, for Python 3.7

Comment: Then the problem can be conda distribution. try to reinstall tenserflow

Comment: First uninstall tenserflow by using "conda remove tensorflow-gpu tensorflow tensorflow-base"

Comment: And then install using "conda install -c anaconda tensorflow" in your Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)

Comment: I got the same problems on colab as well

Comment: Colab uses Keras. So if you change all the imports "tenserflow" to "tensorflow.keras" then the problem can be slowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Anaconda distribution the try to reinstall TensorFlow by using following commands

Remove tenserflow

```
conda remove tensorflow-gpu tensorflow tensorflow-base
```

re-installed tensorflow

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

Reference:- https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow

If your code needs to run on GPU it is better to install tensorflow-gpu by using

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

Reference:- https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu

Also if your project uses keras(Or distribution has keras(ex:-Colab)) then you can use tensorflow insides on keras by using "tensorflow.keras"
Ex:-

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

Change to

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

Answer (score 0):

Python version of Colab has updated .
Add this

```
!pip uninstall keras-nightly

!pip install h5py==2.10.0

!pip install q keras==2.1.6

%tensorflow_version 1.x
```